# XMLhttprequest pending in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

i have such problem.
 I have form

```
<form action="cgi-bin/up.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="downloadForm">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" value="" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="return upload(this.form);">
</form>
```

and upload function

```
function upload(f) {
    var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
    var formData = new FormData(f);
    console.log(formData);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(xmlhttp.status);
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('POST', '/cgi-bin/up.cgi', true);
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
    return false;
}
```

If i try to upload small file(<4KB) everything works fine, but if try to upload file > 4KB chrome has an infinite pending(i see it in developers tools). But if to same things in Mozila - every think goes ok. How i can solve my problem? 
 Thank you.
**UPD** Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 (64-bit) Mozila 32.0.3

Comment: Short question, why are you using a xhr to send the form?

Comment: @David because i need to add progress bar(i delete code with progress bar). Is it so bad to use xhr for it?